# How I can get a quantile function of a discrete distribution, like the binomial distribution

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution

I know it's easy to get a quantile function of a continuous function, but how can I get a quantile function of a discrete distribution, like the binomial distribution?

Comment: One approach is to take advantage of the relationship between the incomplete beta function and the binomial to compute binomial quantiles from software that implements the incomplete beta function or the beta cdf -- or if you're working by hand, you can convert that to values from extensive F tables. This works for a few distributions (Poisson goes with chi-square for example) but outside some specific cases, it's not a general method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that $X$ takes values in the set $\{0,1,2\}$ with probabilities $\{\frac12,\frac14,\frac14 \}$.

Now, let $a\in [0,2]$. What is $P(X\leq a)$?

I'll give a couple example calculations. Then you can try to see how it will generalize.

Let $a=0$, then $P(X\leq 0)=\frac12$, so the quantile function would need to assign the quantile value $0$ to any percentage point in $[0,\frac12)$. At exactly $\frac12$ there will be range of equally acceptable quantiles: $[0,1)$

Now, let $a=1.3$, then $P(X\leq 1.3)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)=\frac34$. This will be true for any $1 \leq a<2$. At the percentage point $\frac34$, the quantile can be represented by any value in $[1,2)$. For percentages in $(\frac12,\frac34)$ the unique quantile will be $1$.

Do you see the pattern, can you see how this would generalize to more realistic distributions like the Binomial? The step-function behavior means that there will be a range of values in $\mathbb{R}$ that have equal claim to being a given quantile. This ambiguity disappears if we restrict the quantiles to the range of $X$.