# Compute the quantile function of this distribution

Tags: r, probability, random-variable, quantiles

I want to compute the quantile function of a Bin(4, 1/3)  random variable and plot it with `R`, but I don't know where to start from.

Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: For just plotting quantile functions in R, note that the common distributions all have four functions (`d...`,`p...`,`q..`,`r...`) defined for them, the density/pmf, the cdf, the quantile function (i.e. the inverse cdf) and random variate generation. See the help `?qbinom`, which identifies the specific function you seek and its arguments).

Comment: The quantile function for discrete variables can be tricky. The quantile function is defined as the inverse of the cumulative distribution function (CDF), but for discrete variables this CDF is [non-injective and non-surjetive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection) and can not be inverted. You have problems like the function not having a continuous domain and a single value maps to many different ones. But there are alternative definitions: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function#General_distribution_function

Comment: `curve(qbinom(x,4,1/3), from=0, to=1)` is quick and dirty, though the vertical steps would be better not shown so `curve(qbinom(x,4,1/3), from=0, to=1, type="p")` gives a different version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that the probability mass function is

$$
f(x) = P(X = x) = 
\begin{cases}
 \frac{16}{81}&\text{if  } x=0\\
\frac{32}{81}&\text{if  } x=1\\
 \frac{24}{81}&\text{if  } x=2\\
 \frac{8}{81}&\text{if  } x=3\\
  \frac{1}{81}&\text{if  } x=4,
\end{cases}
$$
and the cumulative distribution function is

$$
F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if  } x<0\\
\frac{16}{81}  &\text{if  } 0\leq x < 1\\
\frac{48}{81}  &\text{if  } 1\leq x < 2\\
\frac{72}{81}  &\text{if  } 2\leq x < 3\\
\frac{80}{81}  &\text{if  } 3\leq x < 4\\
1  &\text{if  }  4\leq x.
\end{cases}
$$

The quantile function $Q$ is thus

$$
Q(p) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if  } 0< p \leq \frac{16}{81}\\
\cdots & \cdots\\
4 & \text{if  } \frac{80}{81}< p.
\end{cases}
$$

I leave the rest, e.g. the $\cdots$, to you.

[image]

**R code**

```
plot(1, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(-1,5), type="n",
     xlab= "p", ylab= "Q(p)", main = "X ~ Bin(4,1/3)")
abline(v=c(0,1), lwd=1, lty=2, col="lightgray")
segments(x0=0,x1=16/81,y0=0,y1=0, lwd=2)
points(x=16/81,y=0, pch=20, cex=1.4)
#+++++++
segments(x0=16/81,x1=48/81,y0=1,y1=1, lwd=2)
points(x=48/81,y=1, pch=20, cex=1.4)
#+++++++
segments(x0=48/81,x1=72/81,y0=2,y1=2, lwd=2)
points(x=72/81,y=2, pch=20, cex=1.4)
#+++++++
segments(x0=72/81,x1=80/81,y0=3,y1=3, lwd=2)
points(x=80/81,y=3, pch=20, cex=1.4)
#+++++++
segments(x0=80/81,x1=81/81,y0=4,y1=4, lwd=2)
```